# How can we create many new columns in a dataframe in pyspark using withcolumn

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to create around 800 dummy columns in a dataframe which have Null values in it.

I don't want to use `df.withColumn('x', lit(None))` for individual columns as there are many columns.

I tried `map(lambda x: df.withColumn(x, lit(None)), column_list)` but it's not working.

Writing the snippet below also looks like a bad approach.

```python
for column in columns:
    df = df.withColumn(column, lit(None))
```

Can someone suggest what is the best optimum way.

Comment: `for column in columns: df = df.withColumn(column, lit(None))` should be just fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: It just hangs up. I have a lot of records. Approximately 43 Million and there are around 1500 not 800 columns for which I have to create dummy.

Comment: Could this be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)? What is it that you're trying to do? Perhaps something like [`VectorIndexer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorIndexer) could be useful?

Comment: Also, I believe there is a limitation to the number of columns you can have in a spark DataFrame. I don't have any documentation but from past experience, I have found that you run into trouble around 1400 columns.

Comment: Hmm... I also noticed it that the run times are longer but again there's no documentation for it.

Comment: Try it with say 100 dummy columns first so you can see if it's the width of the DataFrame that's the problem.

Comment: >"Also, I believe there is a limitation to the number of columns you can have in a spark DataFrame. I don't have any documentation but from past experience, I have found that you run into trouble around 1400 columns."      Well... OK so I have 200000 (two hundred thousand) or more columns, dynamically determined in a large crosstab type of situation. So what is Spark's solution when columns >> 1400?  Hey we do not all have relational databases with normalized tables kinds of applications.  It is machine learning. Many columns.

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson no easy workaround that I've found for this- the best is to split your table into multiple pieces. I believe the problem is that spark can't split a row over different executors- so if a row has too many columns it can't fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The only approach which you haven't listed that I can think of is to use `rdd`.

Map each row to itself plus `(None,)*len(columns)`

```python
schema = StructType(df.schema.fields + [StructField(c, NullType()) for c in columns])
df = df.rdd.map(lambda row: tuple(row) + (None,)*len(columns)).toDF(schema=schema)
```

Comment: I tried this but without schema. I'll update the thread after applying a schema.